# Training a text model for similarity

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, natural-language, word2vec

I'm training a text similarity model using a two tower approach. The data I'm dealing with has a lot of unusual words that are important (names of people, places) that also don't appear in any pre-trained corpus. I'm finding that using a pre-trained word embedding such as glove is out performing my own trained embedding layer (trained on about 500k short texts), but I would also like to incorporate information about those new words since they are important. What would be the best way to go about doing this? Gensim allows to load pre-trained models, but not to update their vocabulary.